# File not being received properly?

Tags: c++

I'm using sockets to send an EXE file like this:

```
PVOID dll_image = get_dll_by_file(L"C:\\file1.exe");
if (!dll_image)
    printf(_("invalid dll\n"));

send(Connections[conindex],
    reinterpret_cast<char*>(dll_image),
    sizeof(dll_image),
    NULL);
```

```
PVOID get_dll_by_file(LPCWSTR file_path)
{
    HANDLE h_dll = CreateFileW(file_path, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (h_dll == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return NULL;

    DWORD dll_file_sz = GetFileSize(h_dll, NULL);
    PVOID dll_buffer = VirtualAlloc(NULL, dll_file_sz, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

    if (!ReadFile(h_dll, dll_buffer, dll_file_sz, NULL, FALSE) || *(PDWORD)dll_buffer != 9460301)
    {
        VirtualFree(dll_buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        goto exit;
    }

exit:
    CloseHandle(h_dll);
    return dll_buffer;
}
```

And trying to run it as PE like this:

```
char raw[99999];
recv(Connection, raw, sizeof(raw), NULL);

run_image(raw);
```

https://pastebin.com/raw/7ARrTA4K // code run_image

It simply does not run. It is stuck. But it works fine when using a byte array like this:

```
unsigned char rawData[9999] = {
    0x0, 0x0,0x0,0x0 
}
```

I have tried multiple methods, but I face the same issue on all of them.

Comment: `send(..., sizeof(dll_image)` ... `PVOID dll_image` - `PVOID` is `void *`, its size is 8 bytes (or 4, depending on whether you are working in 32 or 64 bit mode). So you sent 8 bytes and are attempting to run that on the other end?

Comment: Add error handling, check how much you have sent and how much you are receiving. You should have done that anyway.

Comment: Do you want to send the entire `file1.exe`? If so, what is `get_dll_by_file` supposed to be doing for you? If you only want a part of it, what happened when you tried reading the documentation to find out how to get the actual size of the DLL? `sizeof` on a pointer tells you the amount of memory needed to store *that pointer*, *not* the pointed-at data. `sizeof` does its work *when the program is compiled*, and cannot do anything about data that results from running the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple bugs in the shown code.

```
        send(Connections[conindex], 
            reinterpret_cast<char*>(dll_image),
            sizeof(dll_image),
            NULL);
```

The first bug is: if you read the documentation for `send`, you will find that it gives you absolutely no guarantees, whatsoever, that the requested number of bytes will be sent over the socket. You must always check the value returned from `send` to determine how many characters were actually sent. In your case, it will be anywhere between 1 and `sizeof(dll_image)`.

You must implement the appropriate logic, if you so wish, to determine whether everything has been sent, and if not call `send` again to attempt to send the remaining, unsent data (and then check if you still need to keep trying).

The same thing is true for `recv` as well. `recv` returnes the number of characters which were actually received. If you are expecting to get more, you will need to `recv` again, and so on.

You will need to implement the appropriate logic in both the sender and the receiver to check the values returned from these system calls, and proceed accordingly.

The second major bug:

```
 sizeof(dll_image)
```

That's just the size of this pointer. It is not how much data it points to. `sizeof` is a ***compile time constant***. You will find that `sizeof(dll_image)` is the same whether it only points to a 1x1 pixel image, or an image containing every page in an encyclopedia.

You need to figure out the size of the image, in bytes, separately, and use the correct number of bytes to send the data.

Comment: The same is true for `ReadFile()`, too. It does not guarantee that the requested number of bytes is actually read, so check the output and call it again if needed. Also, for the `sizeof` issue, you already know the size of the data, it is returned by `GetFileSize()`. So `get_dll_by_file()` should return that value to the caller.